# Cancel next promise if previous failed (synchronously)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I have a case, where Im sending email if previous action succeeded.

```
Promise.all([doSomeAction(), sendMailIfSuccess()]) // both of them are promises
   .then(() => success)
   .catch(() => err);
```

However, if `doSomeAction()` promise fails before `sendMailIfSuccess` resolves, the mail is sent anyways. But it shouldnt.

**Question**: How to invoke `sendMailIfSuccess` promise only if `doSomeAction` resolved? The `sendMailIfSuccess` promise should await for the `doSomeAction` promise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to run those two process in series, and run the second only if the first succeeds, `Promise.all` is not the right tool here - just use `.then` instead:

```
doSomeAction()
  .then(() => sendMailIfSuccess())
  .catch( /* handle errors, including doSomeAction failures */);
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to do some stuff if `sendMailIfSuccess` success? Where I can put second `then`?

Comment: Inside a `.then` afterwards: `.then(() => sendMailIfSuccess()).then(() => console.log('mail sent'))`

Comment: Shouldnt be it `=> sendMailIfSuccess().then(() => 'mail sent')`? Whats the difference?

Comment: That results in nesting `.then`s, which is an antipattern for Promises - the ability to have *flat* `.then` chains is one of the greatest advantages Promises have over callbacks. If you take advantage of it, the code will be easier to read. You *can* if you want, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await` as well

```
async function f(){
  let result1 = await doSomeAction()
  let result2 = await sendMailIfSuccess()
}

try {
 f()
} catch(err) {
 //handle error
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by @CertainPerformance, if you want these methods to run in series. You should call the second method after getting a success response from the first one.

```
doSomeAction()
  .then(res => {
    /* do something with the res, if needed */
    return sendMailIfSuccess();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    /* handle errors */
  });
```

Why `Promise.all(...)` was not the right choice?
As mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

> It is typically used after having started multiple asynchronous tasks to run concurrently and having created promises for their results, so that one can wait for all the tasks being finished.

Similarly, there is `Promise.race(...)` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race), which is used when we need the first resolved or rejected in the iterable.

Comment: **return** sendMailIfSuccess();